# Show that a matrix group is isomorphic to R*

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Let H = \begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&1/a\end{bmatrix}
a is a real number and not equal to zeo.

I want to show that H is isomorphic to R*, but I don't know how to define my mapping function to start with, should I let f(a)=det(a)?

Comment: your determinant would be identically 1 for all such matrices. By R*, do you mean the multiplicative group of the real numbers?

Comment: @Alan I in fact do not know what my mapping function should be, determinant is just guess.

Comment: Hint: your matrices depend only on the parameter $a$.

Comment: @MichaelM. f(a)=ab then? Two matrices multiply each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the binary operation of the group is matrix multiplication and if the matrix is H, then $f(H)=h_{11}^2h_{22}$ would give a one-to-one mapping onto R*. It also satisfies the homomorphism property.

Comment: what is (h11)^2 and h22? Sorry I don't get it.

Comment: h11 is the element at the first row and the first column of the matrix H and h22 is the element at the second row and column.

Comment: then why square the h11?

Comment: h11=a and h22=1/a. So h11^2*h22=(a^2)*(1/a)=a which is a real number

Comment: ah! Thank you, I get it now.